# Get all records in polymorphic relation from a model

Tags: php, sql, laravel, relation

I have Polymorphic relation for category system .

In Post management page I have to load all of the posts categories with polymorphic relation .

I tried this :

```
 $category = new Post();
 $category->categories()->get();
```

but this result is `null`.

How can I load all of the categories that have `categoryable_type` equals to model ?

Comment: what is your database schema, cant understand what you are trying to achieve. to get useful answer pls provide as much information as possible related to the problem

Comment: schema is similar to standard of Laravel polymorphic @NehalHasnayeen